# High or low friction on a sprocket/chainbelt drive

Tags: mechanical, conveyor

We have a segmented belt/chain drive. Both the belt/chain and sprocket are nylon and we have issues with slipping on the sprocket. Would a material change help or do we just need a better tension system?

This is a conveyor that runs 100 ft one way, designed by a semi-local engineering firm 30 years ago. Our parts that are supposed to come in straight but often come in at 30 to 45 degrees currently when it slips multiple times. I am a line worker, not hired as an engineer. I've fixed plenty of other issues with electronic eyes and timings, but this problem has evaded me.

Comment: A photo would help